# apache reverse proxy with SSL gives '400 bad request'

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-16.04, proxypass, odoo

I have an Odoo instance running on port 9069 in an Ubuntu server. Right now, apache is listening on port 8069 and is proxypass-ing this to 9069 (which works fine). The working URL is http://example.com:8069

Now, I need to make this work with SSL on the front end URL. (https://example.com:8069). However this is giving me 400 Bad request error when accessed in a browser. The exact error is:

**Bad Request:
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.Apache/2.4.33 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 8069**

Also I noticed the URL gets changed to http version too.

The following is the virtualhost conf I've used for the domain.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:8069>

  ServerName MySite
  ServerAlias example.com:8069

   SSLEngine on
   #SSLProxyEngine on
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/sslfolder/mysite.key
   SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/sslfolder/mysite.crt
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/sslfolder/mysite.txt

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off

  ProxyPass /longpolling/ http://localhost:8072/
  ProxyPassReverse /longpolling/ http://localhost:8072/

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:9069/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9069/

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Already checked the apache error logs, but there's no useful information there.

Note: There is another virtualhost file for example.com, which is a pretty standard one with 80 and 443 ports configured. (It's just for the website, not odoo). I will post the virtualhost if you think it's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually fixed it using the below modifications.

```
ServerName MySite
```

is changed to

```
ServerName example.com:8069
```

And

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:9069/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9069/
```

is changed to

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:9069/
ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8069/
```

Answer (score 1):

I see this is months old and stumbled on it after a search.  In case this is helpful to future searchers...

I do something similar with a reverse-proxy configuration, though I have not had to change the `ServerName` field and the `ProxyPassReverse` did not require the port number. 
 So using your configuration, I would have tried:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:9069/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps someone:
In my case only some requests were returning 400 code.

I fixed with:

ProxyPreserveHost On

Answer (score 0):

You don't want users typing the port 8069 after the url.

use traditional 80/443 approach and let the proxy handle / hide the 8069 port.

```
Listen 80
##AAdd rewrite rules here to convert http to https
<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerName MySite
  ServerAlias example.com

   SSLEngine on
   #SSLProxyEngine on
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/sslfolder/mysite.key
   SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/sslfolder/mysite.crt
   SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/sslfolder/mysite.txt

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off

 ## if odoo is on local host 
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8069/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8069/
## if odoo is on remote host and you do not want intranet users interception non ssl traffic
  ProxyPass / https://odoo_ip_address:8070
  ProxyPassReverse https://odoo_ip_adress:8070

##odoo http port is 8069 and https port is 8070

</VirtualHost>
```